# mex compiler could not find include path in .h files

Tags: matlab, mex

Hi I'm using MEX in Matlab.
The c code uses boost and a lot of headers are included.

And at first my problem is like this

```
>>mex readTrackletsMex.cpp

readTrackletsMex.cpp 
e:\kitti\tools\devkit\matlab\tracklets.h(7) : fatal error C1083: can not open include file:“boost/serialization/nvp.hpp”: No such file or directory
```

This is because the include path is not specified. So I copied the headers into "/include/boost/XX" and added "-I" flag.

This time it seems that the compiler cannot find the include path in one of the header file.

```
>> mex -Iinclude readTrackletsMex.cpp
readTrackletsMex.cpp 
include\boost/serialization/nvp.hpp(21) : fatal error C1083: can not open include file:“boost/config.hpp”: No such file or directory
```

Any idea on this? How do I specify a "global" include path for the compiler?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the include paths to the environment variables C_INCLUDE_PATH and CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH.  The other issue may be that you put in `-Iinclude`, and not `-I/include`